# How can we use python for loop variable for the django class field?

Tags: python, django

I am sending ajax data to the below view I want to save it in the model I have created (mentioned below). Problem is, in that model I want 26 fields as the months so I created that by the add_to_class inside for loop. I don't know how much months user will input so I have to loop the list in views and save the data as:

```
a = '100000'
b = '120000'
c = '15000'
```

where a, b, c are the months and the rest values will be 0 default.

**Here is the model**

```
class sold(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Buyer = models.ForeignKey(buyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    deposit = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    months = models.IntegerField(default=12)
    tracker = models.IntegerField()
    insurance = models.IntegerField()


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.car} {self.Buyer} {self.total} {self.balance}

for i in ascii_lowercase:
    sold.add_to_class('%s'%i, models.CharField(default=0, max_length=255,null=True, blank=True))
```

NOTE: I have tried range(1, 27) with str and int but it didn't worked out.

**The views.py**

```
def sale_car_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        check = request.POST['car']
        # if soldTo.objects.filter(car__chasis=check).exists():
        #     return HttpResponse('Already Exist')
        if 1==1: #Some condition here
            insurance = request.POST['insurance']
            month = request.POST['month']
            installment = request.POST.getlist('installment')
            installment = [json.loads(item) for item in installment]
            sale = sold(car=pro, Buyer=buyer, total=total, deposit=deposit, balance=balance, 
            tracker=tracker, insurance=insurance, months=month, )
            sale.save()
            installment = installment[0]
            test = sold.objects.get(car=pro, Buyer=buyer)
            # also tried with inline for loop
            for month_l, j in zip(ascii_lowercase, installment):       
                #test(f'{month_l}={j}')  #field should be dynamic by the loop variable OR
                 test.month_l = j
                 test.save()
            return HttpResponse('saved')
    return HttpResponse('failed')
```

Comment: Didn't get it exactly, Are you trying to save a sold car with installments on multiple months?

Comment: @ElayanHamamrah yes, indeed. Some customers wants 12 months, some 6, and some 26. So, the best thing was to get the number of months and loop through on the installment list which we will get from ajax. And then save that with thier accordance month

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, What I would recommend is moving the installments to another model and link it with a primary key or the purchase order references.
With this, you can update and works on the installments in the future or you can track it separately.

So your model will be considered as this (An Example Only):

```
PurchaseID   |   Installment Month    | Status
1            |   10                   | Paid
1            |   12                   | Pending
```

Comment: This will only track the installment paid or not. I want to add the amount too because sometimes customer don't pay the exact amount. And pay the rest with the next month or later. And it would be done by the model I have. The only thing is not working is the loop variable because the for loop is out of the scoop inside the class (someone told me)

Comment: You can add the amount to the table, And subtract it from the original total so it will be pending.
For later, You can have a function to check the total amounts paid and compare it with the original amount to validate if it's fully paid or not.

That's why I recommended keeping the installments separated, Will be easier to be tracked and specify more details on it.